# pandas - show column name + sum in which the sum is higher than zero

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I read my dataframe in with:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv("testFile.txt", sep = "\t", index_col= 0)
```

I got a dataframe like this:

```
cell 17472131 17472132 17472133 17472134 17472135 17472136
cell_0 1 0 1 0 1 0
cell_1 0 0 0 0 1 0
cell_2 0 1 1 1 0 0 
cell_3 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

with pandas I would like to get all the column names in which the sum of the column is > 1 and the total sum.
So I would like:

```
17472131 2
17472133 2
17472135 3
```

I figured out how to get the sums of each column with

```
dataframe.sum(axis=0)
```

but this also returns the columns with a sum lower than 2.. is there a way to only show the columns with a higher value than i.e. 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One pretty neat way is to use lambda function in `loc`:

```
df.set_index('cell').sum().loc[lambda x: x>1]
```

Output:

```
17472131    2
17472133    2
17472135    3
dtype: int64
```

***Details:***  df.sum returns a pd.Series and  we can use `lambda x: x>1` to produce as boolean series which `loc` use boolean indexing to select only True parts of the pd.Series.

Comment: This worked like a charm!! thanks! Do you by any chance know an easy way to write these results to a file?

Comment: Or: `df.loc[:, df.columns.str.isnumeric()].sum().loc[lambda x: x>1]`

Comment: Use `to_csv`  like this: `df_out.to_csv('Out.csv')`

Comment: Like @ansev or you can use `df.select_dtypes(include='number').sum().loc[lambda x: x>1]` without setting index.